# How to implement this scenario for a stable opamp integrator?

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice

I want to make a circuit using opamps and passive components where the input is a pulse train and can be with a frequency between 100kHz upto 3MHz and the duty cycle can be 100% or down to 1ns ON time. I want to average such an input and set a threshold like 0.5V. And if the average is less than 0.5V the final output will be logic zero otherwise logic 5V.

I tried the following approach myself using an RC integrator and a buffer:

[image]

How can this circuit be improved regarding the definite input? Response time I need is less anything than 10ms.

Comment: if you need to output a true/false signal based on a threshold voltage, think about a comparator instead of the opamp buffer. That means: remove the negative feedback and apply a 0.5 V DC signal to the inverting input. The output will be your digital signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a comparator instead of the voltage buffer. The R2 is optional but makes the output slightly hysteretic around 0.5 V input. Be sure to select an opamp/comparator part which has a common mode input range down to within 0.5 V of the negative supply and ideally ral-to-rail output, to provide a full swing digital signal.

[image]